# captcha directive with button angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i tried this in directive .suppose if i entered it correctly it shows true but i want to activate button otherwise button was not valid. 
 This is my Jsfiddle:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hspxaeqa/3/)

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" name="myForm">
    A simple captcha directive in AngularJS
    <br><br>
    <simple-captcha valid="captchaValid"></simple-captcha>
    <br><br>
    <div>valid: {{captchaValid}}</div>
    <button value="submit" id="submit" type="submit"class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #005baa; color: #fff;" ng-click="myForm.$valid && submit()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

thanks in advance, please help to solve this problem.

Comment: where your Jsfiddle link?

Comment: see once i updated

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hspxaeqa/3/

Comment: @chaitanya your code is not correct what are you doing in this `if(a="true"){
    alert("hi");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("false");
    }` where is the variable `a` declared and here you are assigning the value to `a` not condition check.

Comment: I think that the button should be part of the directive, but it's just a suggestion. http://jsfiddle.net/hspxaeqa/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-disabled.

```
<button ng-disabled="!captchaValid" value="submit" id="submit" type="submit"class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #005baa; color: #fff;" ng-click="myForm.$valid && submit()">Submit</button>
```

The button will be enabled only if the captchaValid is true.